# Using Python and Beautiful Soup to grab an IMDB Rating

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I've tried a few different approaches here, and nothing seems to be working, so I'd love any help you can offer!

I'm trying to scrape an IMDB page (for example: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120382/) to grab the rating of the movie.  I managed to do something similar when I was grabbing the text of links on the page.  That worked fine, but this isn't a link, so nothing I've tried has worked.

The rating is definitely available in plain HTML:

```
    "ratingCount": 905028,
"bestRating": "10.0",
"worstRating": "1.0",
"ratingValue": "8.1"
```

Any thoughts on the best way to retrieve that "8.1" value from the page?  Thanks so much for your help!

Cheers,
Ari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rating is a span element with attribute `itemprop=ratingValue`, so it's relatively easy to find it with BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120382/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'ratingValue'}).text)
```

outputs

```
8.1
```

Comment: You are wonderful human being.  That works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `xpath`

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120382/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
rating = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="ratingValue"]//text()')

print(rating)
```